# How to embed iPhone-Wax into app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, lua, iphone-wax

I have just learnt about iPhone-Wax (thanks to SO). Now the documentation is rather sparse for what I am trying to do.

I want to embed it into an Objective-C app. I don't want it to be the main app. Has anyone done it and how can I achieve it?

I would like to use it in the same way LuaObjectiveCBridge is used.

Comment: Welcome to iPhone Wax mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonewax?pli=1

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the question there, and trying some stuff here as well.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586259/lua-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to create an ad-hoc Lua class?! It is as simple as this:

you have a Lua script (script.lua):

```
waxClass{"LuaClass"}
function myMethod(self, object)
 object:doSomething()
end
```

and in your obj-c code:

```
...
luaL_dofile(wax_currentLuaState(), "script.lua");
MyClass *o = [[MyClass alloc] init];
Class LuaClass = NSClassFromString(@"LuaClass");
id luaObject = [[LuaClass alloc] init];
[luaObject performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:o];
...
```

Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/834223#file_wax_retain_issue_app_delegate.m) wrote by Corey.